# Creating a database from a remote computer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have my home workstation computer running Windows 7 and my home server computer running Windows Server 2012 R2. On both PC's I have SQL 2012 installed. What I am wanting to do is be able to access the Server PC from my Workstation PC using SSMS for the purpose of creating and maintaining multiple SQL databases. I was looking for help in how I would go about starting this process.

Comment: Allow the remote connection in your Server PC.

Comment: or fire up SSMS on your win 7 computer, and type the name of the instance of sql server if named instance, or just computer name if you used the default options, and connect. If it can't make sure that remote connections are enabled in the SQL Server configuration tool.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys I will work on this tonight when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create the DB by going on the Server PC first and making a user account with full access. Then logging in from the Windows 7 PC and just right click new database. Thanks for the tips guys.

Comment: just a follow up, you should have setup an "sa" user when installing sql server. you can always use that account to login rather than having to create a new one.